# packages from tcllib not found

Tags: tcl, fedora

I have a strange problem I am using fedora 20 and installed tcllib on my system.

But if I use **package require uri** in example I got an package not found in response.

Does anyone know what the issue here is or how to determine if the tcllib is added in the package index?

Comment: Ok I just discovered it worsk with tcl 8.5 but not with 8.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl looks up packages in two ways: with `auto_path` and with `tcl::tm::path`.

### 1. The `auto_path` — the traditional mechanism.

When you do `package require`, the package manager looks to see if the package is already present, or if instructions for obtaining the package from the filesystem are present. If neither of these is true, it asks the `package unknown` handler to load it (strictly, it's the handler installed using the `package unknown` command). The default implementation of that handler loads packages by looking for `pkgIndex.tcl` files in the directories on your `auto_path`, and their *immediate* subdirectories.

`auto_path` is a global variable holding a *Tcl list* of directories to search. You can probably just `lappend` the right place to it. `pkgIndex.tcl` is a Tcl script that describes how to make the package available, which it does by calling an appropriate `package ifneeded` command. The *actual* loading of the

Once a package is required that isn't present but its instructions for obtaining *are*, Tcl will simply `eval` those instructions: they're just a plain old script (that usually just calls `source` and/or `load` to do the grunt work).

### 2. Tcl modules — the new (in 8.5) mechanism.

The Tcl module system uses a different search system managed with the `tcl::tm::path` command. The `tcl::tm::path list` subcommand will tell you where it looks (a huge list, to be honest) and you can use the `tcl::tm::path add` subcommand to extend the path with extra locations to search. Tcl modules have the entire package placed into a single file (with the extension `.tm`) and have a structured name so that they can avoid having a separate `pkgIndex.tcl` file; the TM loader can synthesise the `package ifneeded` calls from the filename itself (in all cases, this is done with `source`; there are some clever ways to package binary code inside files so they can be `load`ed, but they're far outside the scope of this answer).

At that point, you're back to the `source` of the file when the package is actually required; that part is the same whether you're using a module or a traditional package.

The module system is much faster than the traditional search mechanism since it doesn't need to open any files to figure out what to do: it just uses `glob` with the right options. It is, however, less flexible in how things can be packaged: multi-file packages (e.g., almost anything you make yourself) can't be made into modules (well, not without extra work).

Comment: Section 1, second paragraph, the last sentence is cut off "The actual loading of the ...". I want to know the rest of the story!